# Write a function which takes in a string and returns the counts of each string

Tags: javascript

I'm literally stuck at solving this simple question. Anyway I found out another way to solve this but I couldn't figure out the issue with my code.

```
function charCout(str)
{
    str = str.toLowerCase();
    var f  = {};

    for(let i =0;i<str.length;i++)
    {
        if(str[i] === " ")
        {
            continue;
        }
        else{
            if(str[i] in Object.keys(f))
            {
                f[str[i]] += 1;
            }
            else
            {
                f[str[i]] = 1;
            }
        }
    }
  return(f);   
}




input: charCout("my name is Khan23")
expected output: {2: 1,3: 1,a: 2,e: 1,h: 1,i: 1,k: 1,m: 2,n: 2,s: 1,y: 1}
what i got: {2: NaN,3: NaN,a: 1,e: 1,h: 1,i: 1,k: 1,m: 1,n: 1,s: 1,y: 1}
```

Comment: You want simply `str[i] in f`, not `str[i] in Object.keys(f)`. If you were getting the array of all keys, you'd need to do `Object.keys(f).includes(str[i])` (but that's horribly inefficient).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the wrong to way to check if key is in object or not.

You can contract your `if-else` to single line using `||` operator.

```
f[str[i]] = f[str[i]] + 1 || 1
```

It checks whether `f[str[i]]` already exists or not. If `str[i]` is not key of `f` then `f[str[i]]` will return `undefined` and `undefined + 1` will be `NaN`.

`NaN` is a falsy value so `NaN || 1` will evaluate to `1`.

If the `f[str[i]]` exists then it will return any number greater than `0` so it will be set to `f[str[i]] + 1`(incremented by one)

```js
function charCount(str)
{
    str = str.toLowerCase();
    var f  = {};

    for(let i =0;i<str.length;i++)
    {
        if(str[i] !== " ")
        {
            f[str[i]] = f[str[i]] + 1 || 1 
        }
    }
  return(f);   
}
console.log(charCount("my name is Khan23"))
```

#### Explanation:

You can also use `reduce()`.

```js
const charCount = str => str
                          .split(' ')
                          .join('')
                          .split('')
                          .reduce((ac,a) => 
                              (ac[a] = ac[a] + 1 || 1, ac), 
                          {})


console.log(charCount("my name is Khan23"))
```

Comment: `||` doesn't check whether the key exists. If you really want to do it like this, please explain how exactly it works.

Comment: @Bergi I have added an explanation.

Comment: Thanks. I would think `f[str[i]] = (f[str[i]] || 0) + 1` is better to understand, though. Or just go for the explicit `(str[i] in f ? f[str[i]] : 0) + 1`

Comment: I did it exactly the same way you did @maheer. I don't have problem with this method. I'm just trying to figure out what's the issue with the above code(my code)

Answer (score 1):

Simply see if the property exists by type coercion like: `if(f[str[i]])`

```js
function charCount(str)
{
    str = str.toLowerCase();
    var f  = {};

    for(let i =0;i<str.length;i++)
    {
        if(str[i] === " ")
        {
            continue;
        }
        else{
            if(f[str[i]])
            {
                f[str[i]] += 1;
            }
            else
            {
                f[str[i]] = 1;
            }
        }
    }
  return(f);   
}

console.log(charCount('the value is 0000'))
```

Comment: Technically that isn't a real check for it *existing* but works in this case since value is always truthy when it does exist

Comment: @charlietfl Thanks. I modified the condition to patch when `str[i]`  is 0

Comment: @CharlieH `|| 0` doesn't make any sense in a condition

Comment: @Bergi True. I was mistaken. Edited.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `str.split("")` to get the list of chars and then do something like

```
const splitted = str.split("");
const result = {};
splitted.map(letter => result[letter] ? result[letter]++ : result[letter] = 1)
```

it is just an idea

Answer (score 0):

using `Object.keys(f).includes(str[i])` instead of `str[i] in Object.keys(f)` is the solution

`in` operator primarily would work to check if Object provides a particular attribute

Mozilla doc on [in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in) and [Array.prototype.includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) shall help.

following variation of your function would work

```
function charCout(str)
{
    str = str.toLowerCase();
    var f  = {};

    for(let i =0;i<str.length;i++)
    {
        if(str[i] === " ")
        {
            continue;
        }
        else{
            if(Object.keys(f).includes(str[i]))
            {
                f[str[i]] += 1;
            }
            else
            {
                f[str[i]] = 1;
            }
        }
    }
  return(f);   
}
```

Comment: Ty abhishek. Now i figured out the issue with my code.
we can't filter array with the value at index using "in" operator.

Answer (score 0):

You can take advantage of [`String.protoype.split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) and [`Array.prototype.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to solve this. Check the comments in the code for details:

```js
const charCount = s => {
  //Create an array of characters found in the string (filtering out spaces)
  const chars = s.split('').filter(char => char.trim());

  //Use reduce to create an occurrence map - increment by 1 each time a character is encountered
  return chars.reduce((accum, char) => {
    accum[char] = accum[char] ? accum[char] + 1 : 1;
    return accum;
  }, {});
};

console.log(charCount("my name is Khan23"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your helpful suggestions. i finally figured out whats wrong with my code.

inputs and outputs of my defected code is as follows:

input: charCout("my name is Khan23")

expected output: {2: 1,3: 1,a: 2,e: 1,h: 1,i: 1,k: 1,m: 2,n: 2,s: 1,y: 1}

what i got: {2: NaN,3: NaN,a: 1,e: 1,h: 1,i: 1,k: 1,m: 1,n: 1,s: 1,y: 1};

I've used "in" operator to find out whether a specific value of string is present the Object.keys(f) array. That's exactly where I went wrong.

after referring to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in  i got to know "in" can't be used to filter array using value at index.